# How to add a midpoint to a scatter plot colormap in Python

Tags: matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have made a little project that computes the intrinsic value of a list of stocks based their projected future cash flows and other metrics. Anyway, here is a scatterplot of some stock examples. As you can see the stocks above the gray line are undervalued and those below are overvalued. I want to have all data points be correlated to where they occur on the plot. I need a way to set a midpoint on the plot so that data points like PFE, AVGO, and QCOM show up a shade of green and points close to the line show up a shade of yellow. The 'RdYlGr' colormap is the closest thing I can find but depending on outliers in the points the colors don't always like up how I need them to.  Does anyone know how to set a midpoint on a colormap? Here is my code that I used for the plot. Fyi 'value' is the intrinsic value of the stock, 'price' is its current trading price, and 'ratio' is the intrinsic value divided by the current price.

```
plt.style.use('seaborn')
plt.title('Price vs Intrinsic Value Scatterplot')
plt.xlabel('Market Cap (billions)')
plt.ylabel('Total Intrinsic Value (billions)') 
plt.scatter(price, value, s = 20, c = ratio, edgecolor = 'k', cmap = 'RdYlGn')
for i, label in enumerate(name):
    plt.annotate(label, (price[i], value[i]))
myMax = max(max(price), max(value))
plt.plot([0,myMax], [0,myMax], color = 'gray')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: There is a way to define a custom colormap, yes. Maybe this is what you want? I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you mean by "set a midpoint on a colormap".

Comment: Okay, I'll try to avoid being too cryptic: I would suggest that you look at using a `LinearSegmentedColormap` (https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.html) if the custom colormap is what you are after.

Comment: Your post is missing reproducible sample data.  A simple approach to get the yellow at zero, is `vmax = max(max(ratio),-min(ratio));  vmin = -vmax` and then `plt.scatter(...., vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)`.